# on firefox although i update my code,old css codes still works

Tags: css, browser

I updated my site, changed some css code and other codes and i uploaded all files with filezilla. It works on chrome,but not firefox and when i look the codes with firebug,i saw the css file was previous version.how it could be that new version on chrome but not firefox ?

Comment: Do a clean refresh. (Ctrl+f5)

Comment: Clear your cache and check.

Comment: thank you so much @BhojendraNepal

Comment: What technolody you are using ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening as firefox is using chached css as it is not aware that your application has changed the files.
You should clear your cache for now and for avoiding it in future, add the proper headers like  Cache-Control as no caching

Answer (score 1):

Clear Cache.

Short Cut- Ctrl+F5

OR

Firefox ->Options->Privacy->Clear your recent history->set the Time range to clear to Everything -> uncheck everything except for Cache -> Clear Now .